# Powerbuilder preprocessor directive and DEBUG not working

Tags: sybase, preprocessor, powerbuilder

I'm having some buggy behavior with DEBUG and precompiler directives.

I have a PowerBuilder application. In the production environment it logs in using a certificate, but in Dev, to make things easier on myself I want to login with username and password. I added this bit of code:

```
#if defined DEBUG then
   MessageBox("Info","Running in DEBUG mode, certificates disabled!")
   ibool_certlogin = FALSE
#else
   ibool_certlogin = TRUE
#end if
```

This seems to only work sometimes. When I first load the project, and run it it fails. Meaning, even though I'm in the IDE and DEBUG should be defined, the message box *still* does not display, and the certificates are *still* enabled.

I can however correct the behavior with a somewhat arbitrary change. Specifically, if I open the module this code is in, and then arbitrarily type a space, and then save. Then I run the project the message box correctly displays and the certificates are correctly disabled. It continues to function correctly until I close PowerBuidler IDE and reopen it.

Has anyone experience this or know a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you need to rebuild the project if you make a a change in a directive, a simple run is not enough.

A simpler solution if you need a specific behaviour when running from the IDE is :

```
IF handle(getapplication()) = 0 THEN
    // running from the IDE
    ...
ELSE
    // running from EXECUTABLE
END IF
```